# Github commit comments

Tags: github, github-api, github-for-windows

I have a project on Git hub that I have been committing to frequently. I assumed that the comments I committed along with the files could be downloaded in some way. As a text file or even via the API but I can not see a way to download the comments.

Is there a way I can download a text file containing all the commit comments I have submitted?

Comment: When you say "commit comments" you mean the commit __messages__ or the ___comments___ on the commits github allows you to make ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested, but my guess is that using this - https://github.com/schacon/simplegit-progit
You can do something like this - git log --pretty=format:"%s" > comments.txt

And here's some info about the library - http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History

Answer (score 0):

you will get all commits in file

.git/logs/HEAD

so clone the code .copy above file in to another file.  It will contain all logs

Another option is :

pass the output of following command in to one file

git rev-list --all --pretty=oneline

so final command will be

git rev-list --all --pretty=oneline > allcommits.txt